# Bootstrap - Columns default value

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

On the [bootstrap grid system](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid) documentation says:

> *Content should be placed within columns, and only columns may be immediate children of rows.*

So on the following example for smartphones and tablets:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12">Column One</div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12">Column Two</div>
</div>
```

Do we have to set the classes **col-xs-12 col-sm-12** when a column should fill the row width or is there a default class that we can set for both devices? If we don't set the **col** classes, the content is pushed left and right due to the negative margins on the **.row** class.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As Bootstrap is mobile first, if you set `.col-xs-12`, your div will have a full with on **every** device. This means you don't have to set `.col-sm-12`.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12">
    <!--
      12-col on xs/sm/md/lg 
    -->
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-6-md">
    <!--
      12-col on xs/sm
      6-col on ms/lg
    -->
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-6-md col-12-lg">
    <!--
      12-col on xs/sm
      6-col on md
      12-col on lg
    -->
  </div>
</div>
```

Plus, the default value **is precisely** `.col-xs-12`. This means you don't even have to specify it:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <!--
      12-col on xs/sm
      6-col on md
    -->
  </div>
</div>
```